# RegExp to get text in a key value pair separated by a colon

Tags: javascript, regex

I have my Regexp example here: https://regex101.com/r/kE9mZ7/1

For the following string:

key_1: some text, maybe a comma, ending in a semicolon; key_2: text with possibly no ending semicolon, but could be

I would like to do something like the following:

```
var regEx_attrVal = /[\w :].*?(?=;|$)/g;
var results = attrs.match(regEx_attrVal);
      for(i=0;i<results.length;++i) {
        var split = results[i].split(':');

        preColon = split[0].trim();
        postColon = split[1].trim();

        //log preColon and postColon to console

      }
```

the end result should be something like:

```
//results[0]
preColon: key_1
postColon: some text, maybe a comma, ending in a semicolon

//results[1]
preColon: key_2
postColon: text with possibly no ending semicolon, but could be
```

My regexp is definitely wrong, hoping the SO community can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`(\w+):\s*([^;]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fS1lD8/1), there will be no need splitting. Just access Groups 1 and 2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nice! you saved me time and frustration - thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes please, as that is the answer to the question. I wish I could also mark gurvinder372's answer, because it does solve the problem as well, although yours is directly related to the post of how to do it in Regex. Any idea on the performance difference between regex and split approaches when dealing with something like 1000 of these queries?

Comment: As for the performance, the only way to tell  is to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex way to extract those values:

```
/(\w+):\s*([^;]*)/gi
```

or (as identifiers should begin with `_` or a letter):

```
/([_a-z]\w*):\s*([^;]*)/gi
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS1lD8/2)

```js
var re = /([_a-z]\w*):\s*([^;]*)/gi; 
var str = 'key_1: some text, maybe a comma, ending in a semicolon; key_2: text with no ending semicolon';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.body.innerHTML += m[1] + ": " + m[2] + "<br/>";
}
```

**Pattern  details**:

- `([_a-z]\w*)` - Group 1 matching an identifier starting with `_` or a letter and followed with 0+ alphanumeric/underscore symbols
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^;]*)` - 0+ characters other than `;`. The use of a *negated character class* eliminates the need of using lazy dot matching with `(?:$|;)` group after it. **NOTE** that `*` quantifier makes the value optional. If it is required, use `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `g` modifier, [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lC1cZ9/1)

If regex is not mandatory then try

```
var input = "key_1: some text, maybe a comma, ending in a semicolon; key_2: text with no ending semicolon";
var keyValues = input.split(";");
keyValues.forEach( function(val){
  var keyValue = val.split( ":" );
  alert( "precolon " + keyValue[0] );
  alert( "postcolon " + keyValue[1] );
});
```

Comment: Not only `/g`, OP regex can match a blank string.

Comment: @gurvinder372 This solves the problem equally well - thank you! Additionally it is much easier for me, as I feel lost with Regex at this point (I wish I had more time to learn it all). Any idea of the performance difference between using the regex approach versus the split approach when dealing with lets say 1000 of these queries?

Comment: @RonI glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This regex should to the trick for you:

```
/(\w+):([^;]*)/g
```

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/kE9mZ7/4)